# Initialising component only when the model where its placed shows

Tags: angular, angular-components

Ive a page at which a model dialog has to be shown while clicking on a button say New User. So the model dialog has form fields on it for the new user entry. Along with that there is another component on the model which is actually a grid itself.

But the grid has to be load only when the model shows. So the grid content can dynamically change according to the model values. But the problem am facing is when the page loads first time the component in the model also initialises and loads. How can I avoid that and loads that grid component in model loads only when the model been shown

Here is part of my model component with the third component

```
  </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <app-userlist [templateCategoryId]="0" ></app-userlist>
                    </div>

                </div>
```

And here is the app-userlist component init part

```
import { Component, Inject, OnInit, TemplateRef, ViewChild, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, RequestOptionsArgs, RequestOptions, Headers, } from '@angular/http';
import { HttpParams } from '@angular/common/http'
import { MatDialog, MatDialogRef } from "@angular/material";
import { AppService } from "../../../services/singletons/app.service";
import { NotificationService } from "../../../services/notification.service";
import { MessageType } from '../../../models/MessageType';


@Component({
    selector: 'app-userlist',
    templateUrl: 'userlist.component.html'
})
export class UserListComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input() public templateCategoryId: number;

    ngOnInit(): void {
        if (isNaN(this.templateCategoryId)) {
            this.templateCategoryId = 0;
        }
        this.loadUserList(this.templateCategoryId);
    }
```

Also when the model shows (By edit or new button) the parameter [templateCategoryId] value has to be changed dynamically. For example if its new the value as 0 or when edit the value should be the ID of the editing user.

Any suggestions highly appreciated..

Comment: What modal you are using? Is it the plain bootstrap modal or some library like ng2-bootstrap/ngx-bootstrap?

Comment: Plain bootstrap modal
<div class="modal fade" id="newTemplateCategoryModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog  modal-lg" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
......
.....

Answer (score 0):

Try to listen modal show/shown events.

As per the [documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/)

**shown.bs.modal** event is fired when the modal is completely visible

```
$('#newTemplateCategoryModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
  //Your code that you want to perform after the modal load 
})
```

Add this in **ngAfterViewInit** and see if it works.